# php find earliest date in the format dd/mm/yyyy in a text file

Tags: string, date

I have a text file in the following format

```
03/12/2023 06 This is the text in the line
03/12/2023 06 This is the text in the line
03/12/2023 06 This is the text in the line
03/12/2023 06 This is the text in the line
22/11/2023 06 This is the text in the next line
22/11/2023 06 This is the text in the next line
03/11/2023 06 This is another text in the line
03/11/2023 06 This is another text in the line
03/11/2023 06 This is another text in the line
04/12/2023 06 This is yet another text in the line
04/12/2023 06 This is yet another text in the line
```

Which is read into an array $data, from this array, I want to output the earliest date which in this case would be 03/11/2023